# which tools we use for implementing Sybil attack simulation in VANEt

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I want to know which and how many simulation tools we need to implement a Sybil attack in VANET. I read some where SUMO alone is enough but most of people recommend to use combination of SUMO, Omnet++ and Veins. What will be the instructions and data flow here?

Comment: ns2 : sybil-vanet-12-ex-1.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NFohjUHuq7tKBBvyQAW_KOnMalBT40Hx/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In Sybil attack, an intruder tries to acquire a number of legible nodeIds, which appear and function as a set of distinct nodes.

Sumo alone may not suffice for the purpose of simulating Sybil attack as it can only generate node movements. The properties of the nodes can be customised using veins that's available as a project in omnet++ framework.

Try learning by following the steps given on veins.car2x.org about using veins. TraciDemo11p is a sample application available inside veins project.

Happy learning